# How to fix "Cannot invoke "java.awt.Point.getX()" because "this.p" is null"

Tags: java, inheritance, nullpointerexception, point

For an inheritance practice assignment, I have a class `Square` which extends rectangle, and here are the relevant methods:

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    private Point p;
    private int sideLength;
    public Square(Point p, int sideLength){
        super(p);
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getName() + "\nCenter point: (" + p.getX() + ',' + p.getY() + ") \nSide Length: " + sideLength + " \nArea: " + this.getArea() + " \nPerimeter: " + this.getPerimeter();
    }


}
```

there's also a getArea() and getPerimeter() method but neither of those are causing this issue.
I have a separate class to test this one:

```
public class SquareTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Square> squareList = new ArrayList<>();
        Point p1 = new Point(1, 1);
        Point p2 = new Point(1, 2);
        Point p3 = new Point(4, 1);
        Point p4 = new Point(2, 3);
        Point p5 = new Point(5, 4);
        Square one = new Square(p1, 1);
        Square two = new Square(p2, 2);
        Square three = new Square(p3, 4);
        Square four = new Square(p4, 4);
        Square five = new Square(p5,5);
        squareList.add(one);
        squareList.add(two);
        squareList.add(three);
        squareList.add(four);
        squareList.add(five);
        for (Square each : squareList){
            System.out.println(each.toString());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

What it's supposed to do is print out the toString() result for each of the five square objects, where one square looks like this:

```
Square
Center point: (1,1)
Side Length: 1
Area: 1
Perimeter: 1
```

but instead i get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.Point.getX()" because "this.p" is null
    at Square.toString(Square.java:21)
    at SquareTest.main(SquareTest.java:23)
```

I'm confused as to why it thinks `this.p` is null when I've clearly instantiated five Point objects. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `toString()` method for any of the squares individually, to see if it still throws this error before the loop?

Comment: You are _shadowing_ `Rectangle.p` in your `Square.p`.

Answer (score 4):

`NullPointerException` was caused because you haven't initialized the `p` in `Square` class. Yu have just passed it to the `Rectangle` constructor so it is the `p` in `Rectangle` class which is getting initialized.

Since you are not using the point object in your `Square` rather than just passing it to the super class, there is no need to declare a `Point` object in the `Square` class. If your `Rectangle` class has a getter method for `Point p` then, you could use that in the `Square` class.

Assuming that `Rectangle` class has a getter method for `p`, You could refactor your `Square` class to :

```java
public class Square extends Rectangle {
    private int sideLength;
    public Square(Point p, int sideLength){
        super(p);
        this.sideLength = sideLength;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getName() 
               + "\nCenter point: (" + getP().getX() + ',' + getP().getY()
               + ") \nSide Length: " + sideLength
               + " \nArea: " + this.getArea()
               + " \nPerimeter: " + this.getPerimeter();
    }
}
```